# Transformar JSONArray em Objeto da classe

Tags: java, android, json, mobile, objetos

Eu estou consumindo uma API no meu aplicativo que me retorna um Array de nomes, criei uma classe para atribuir cada nome a 1 instância porém estou tendo problemas na hora de pegar esse JSONArray e transformar em objeto, todos os métodos que tentei não deram certo, alguém sabe como fazer isso em Java (Android) ?

```
public void jsonToObj(JSONArray resultadoDaPesquisa) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = resultadoDaPesquisa;

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultadoDaPesquisa.toString());
        System.out.println("resultado " + jsonObject);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":67377,"name":"Shiren the Wanderer 4: The Eye of God and the Devil's Navel"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Lucas. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Lucas, edite sua pergunta postando o código que já tentou. Lembre-se, este é um site que gira ao redor de códigos. Sem eles, pouca ou nenhuma ajuda conseguirão lhe oferecer.

Comment: Editado. Agora com uns dos vários códigos que tentei.

Comment: Lucas, seria bom ver o json. Poderia colar aqui pra gente!

Comment: O JSONArray é esse: [{"id":67377,"name":"Shiren the Wanderer 4: The Eye of God and the Devil's Navel"}] me retorna um id e um nome, isso que vc quer ?

Answer (score 0):

Este é o código que utilizo para ser JSON e transformar em objeto:

```
public class JsonReader {

    static String secretKeyCaptcha = "6Ld5NXMUAAAAAOXPv-EbwycOMHfoxJrSSdLcLl-I";

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String cep) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/").openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    public static JSONObject validarTokenRecaptcha(String token) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKeyCaptcha + "&response=" + token);
        InputStream is = new URL(
                "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKeyCaptcha + "&response=" + token)
                        .openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Depois é so fazer:

```
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            JsonReader jr = new JsonReader();
            jsonObj = jr.readJsonFromUrl(frete.getCepDestino());

enderecoDestino = jsonObj.get("logradouro").toString() + " - " + jsonObj.get("bairro").toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda ! 
Consegui fazer de uma outra forma.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i<resultadoDaPesquisa.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject = resultadoDaPesquisa.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
            String nome = jsonObject.getString("name");

            Anuncio anuncio = new Anuncio();
            anuncio.setUid(id);
            anuncio.setTitulo(nome);

            System.out.println(anuncio);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) para facilitar o trabalho.

Com ela, a partir da String de JSON que você recebe, você consegue criar uma instância da classe desejada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SuaClasse suaClasse = gson.fromJson(stringJson, SuaClasse.class);
```

[Aqui](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) está o Guia do Usuário da lib.

Comment: Eu tentei, porém não consegui por ser um JSONArray, talvez estivesse fazendo errado ou precisasse de uma conversão.